# MissingMethodException for custom renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When loading my MainPage Visual Studio goes into break mode with the following error

> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Test.Renderers.PostListViewAndroid

I updated my Custom Renderer class to support 2.5 since *Context is obsolete as of version 2.5*

My custom renderer is

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PostListView), typeof(PostListViewAndroid))]
namespace SocialNetwork.Droid.Renderers
 {
public class PostListViewAndroid: ListViewRenderer
{

    public PostListViewAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.SetSelector(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
    }
}
}
```

And the PostListView is simply

```
public class PostListView : ListView
{
}
```

Comment: can you post code snippet for PostListViewAndroid class ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Posted the wrong class :P replaced in edit now.

Comment: Add a default constructor: 
public PostListViewAndroid(){}

Comment: @FaizanRabbani That actually worked except it put a green unline saying Its obsolete as of version 2.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Xamarin.Forms >= 2.5 you need to use `ListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)` as you know

This is the source for the current `ListViewRenderer`

```
public class ListViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<ListView, AListView>, SwipeRefreshLayout.IOnRefreshListener
{
    ...

    public ListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        AutoPackage = false;
    }

    [Obsolete("This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use ListViewRenderer(Context) instead.")]
    public ListViewRenderer()
    {
        AutoPackage = false;
    }
```

Notice the `Obsolete` Attribute, meaning you don't need it. However it seems your problem is that your packages and references are out of alignment. Id try the following steps

**Step 1**

1. Clean Solution
2. Delete bins and objs directions in all projects
3. Restart visual studio
4. Rebuild

---

**Step 2**

Try updating all packages for solution in the package package console

```
Update-Package  –reinstall
```

After this step, if it still hasn't worked try step 1 again

Answer (score 2):

If base class does not have default empty constructor (in your case `ListViewRenderer`) - you cannot do this. If it has, then add below

```
public PostListViewAndroid()
    {

    }
```

Its for simple reason : when derive class in instantiated, first base class constructor is invoked for initialization. So if there is no default constructor in base class, its not going to work out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but my case that I've forgotten to make the context contractor as a public.

I change this:

```
PostListViewAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
```

to this:

```
public PostListViewAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
```